# discord.js status 'Cannot read property 'setActivity' of null'

Tags: javascript, discord, status

I'm getting this error, when trying to run my bot:

client.user.setActivity(status, { type: 'WATCHING' })
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setActivity' of null

```
console.log('fentabot')

let statuses=[
    'ɪɴɢʏᴇɴ',
    'ʟᴜᴀ ᴇxᴇᴄᴜᴛᴏʀ',
    'ᴍᴏᴅ ᴍᴇɴᴜ'
]
setInterval(function(){
    let status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.lenght)]
    client.user.setActivity(status, { type: 'WATCHING' })
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to run this code once your bot is ready, otherwise it won't work :

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    // Place your code here
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting te error. https://pastebin.com/1jYZx90N this is my whole code

Comment: @ImreVeres You're trying to edit your status every 10 seconds. You're obviously going to get rate limited in a few minutes if not seconds. You should try multiplying this value by at least 60 to make it change every 10 minutes

Comment: @ImreVeres by the way, since your "client" us called "fasz", you'll have to replace `client.on("ready" ...` with `fasz.on("ready" ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log('fentabot')

let statuses = [
    'ɪɴɢʏᴇɴ',
    'ʟᴜᴀ ᴇxᴇᴄᴜᴛᴏʀ',
    'ᴍᴏᴅ ᴍᴇɴᴜ'
]
let status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.lenght)]

setInterval(() {
    client.user.setActivity(status, { type: 'WATCHING' })
}, 5000)
```

Note: Having 2000 milliseconds can result in DISCORD API abuse, use 5000 milliseconds

Answer (score -1):

statuses.lenght won't work, coz it's a spelling mistake, no probs everyone makes this mistake. Replace it with statuses.length.